# ¿Como hago para que el modal no me cambie el id?

Tags: python-3.x, modal, flask

[image: En vez de que se actualice victor, se actualiza selene]
Buenas noches el problema que tengo que ya llevo horas tratando de solucionar es que al hacer uso de un procedimiento almacenado en mysql e imprimirlo con jinja me arroja el id del atleta entre otras cosas(en este caso mi usuario) bien, el problema esta en que a la hora de llamar a una funcion mediante un modal que hace un update, el id aparece cambiado y no tengo idea porque.
Lo que ya hice es comprobar que a la hora de imprimir los usuarios estos si cuentan con el id correcto, es a la hora de llamar a un procedimiento con un modal que se cambia

Aqui les dejo el codigo del html

```
    {% extends "base.html" %}
    {% block content %}
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    
    <head>
      <link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='/css/listar.css' ) }}" rel="stylesheet" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    
    <body>
      <h1 class="titulo"> Lista de Atletas a tu Cargo </h1>
    
      <div class='centraTabla'>
        <div class="buscador">
          <input type="text" class="campotexto" id="search" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Escriba para buscar">
        </div>
    
        <table class="table table-striped  border-bottom " id="tabla">
          <thead class="bg-primary text-white">
            <tr class="tabla">
              <th>Nombre</th>
              <th>Categoria</th>
              <th>Operaciones</th>
            </tr>
          <tbody>
            {%for d in atleta%}
            <tr>
              <td>{{ d.1+' '+d.2+' '+d.3 }}</td>
              <td>{{ d.4 }}</td>
              <td>
    
                <a  class="boton_personalizado3" href="/insert_medidas/{{ d.0 }}">Insertar Medidas</a>
                <a  class="boton_personalizado3" href="/insert_records/{{ d.0 }}">Insertar Record</a>
                <p>{{ d.0 }}</p>
                <a type="button" class="boton_personalizado3" data="{{d.0}}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#add_data_Modal2" 
                        onclick=acCat(data)>Actualizar Categoria</a>
                        
                
              </td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
          </tbody>
          <thead>
        </table>
    
      </div>
      {%for d in atleta%}
      <div id="add_data_Modal2" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
         <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
           <h4 class="modal-title" style="color:black">Modificar Categoria</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
           <form action="/actualizar_Cat/{{d.0}}" method="POST" id="insert_form">
            <label>Inserte nueva Categoria:</label>
            <input type="text" name="categoria" id="categoria" list="exampleList">
            <datalist id="exampleList">
              <option value="Principiante">
              <option value="Intermedio">
              <option value="Avanzado">
              <option value="RX">
            </datalist>
            <br />
            <input type="submit" name="insert" id="insert" value="Insert" class="btn btn-success" />
           </form>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      {% endfor %}
      <script>  
        function acCat(id){  
          
            cad = "/actualizar_Cat/" + id
            $("#ruta").attr('href', cad)
         
        } 
      </script>
      
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script>
        function myFunction() {
          $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#search").keyup(function () {
              _this = this;
              // Show only matching TR, hide rest of them
              $.each($("#tabla tbody tr"), function () {
                if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf($(_this).val().toLowerCase()) === -1)
                  $(this).hide();
                else
                  $(this).show();
              });
            });
          });
        } 
      </script>
    
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    </body>
    
    </html>
    {% endblock %}
```

Ahora les dejo mis funciones en python 3

```
#Con esta se carga el template de arriba
@auth.route('/seleccionados', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def seleccionados():
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    cur.callproc("infoatleta",[current_user.id])
    rv = cur.fetchall()
return render_template('seleccionados.html',atleta=rv)

#Este es el metodo que se manda a llamar mediante el modal
@auth.route('/actualizar_Cat/<id>',methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def actCat(id):
    print ("EL ID DEL ATLETA ES"+str(id))
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    if request.method == 'POST': 
        cat = request.form['categoria']
        if cat=="Principiante":
            idcat=1
        elif cat=="Intermedio":
            idcat=2
        elif cat=="Avanzado":
            idcat=3
        elif cat=="RX":
            idcat=4
        cur.callproc("actualizarCategoria", [id, idcat])
        mysql.connection.commit()
        cur.close()
    return  redirect(url_for('auth.seleccionados'))
```